# Keep Clipboard Info after closing Program

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

I have an expanded DataGridView user control and some other NumericUpDown controls where the user can copy/paste information within my software and other software like Excel.

My problem is that when the user closes my software the information in the clipboard is lost. I would like this clipboard information to be kept, in case the information is not very big (maybe asking the user, as Microsoft Office Software does).

How can I leave this information in the clipboard, so that the user can use it afterwards?

Comment: How do you add the data to the clipboard? Please show us the code.

Comment: I used Clipboard class as stuartd commented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [overload of Clipboard.SetDataObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs5ebdfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that allows you to pass in a value indicating what should happen to the data when the app exits:

> true if you want data to remain on the Clipboard after this application exits; otherwise, false.

Comment: Only out of curiosity: Why using `SetDataObject` where you have to define whether to keep the data or not while [Clipboard.SetText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydby206k(v=vs.110).aspx) keeps the data by default?

Comment: Probably because the [documentation for SetText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs5ebdfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implies that is the case, but isn't explicit about it.

Comment: Well so unless one is adding a string to the clipboard, one should use `SetDataObject` instead of `SetText`?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense: If you want to add a (serializable) object to the clipboard, then use `SetDataObject`, but if you're just adding text, use `SetText`